# Failing to assign the right value to field?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

For some reason, even though I assign it the field "Rank" is 0, when in the database is it currently set to 8.

```
using (var dbConnection = Program.Server.DatabaseHandler.Connection)
{
    dbConnection.SetQuery("SELECT users.id,users.username,users.rank,users.motto,users.look,users.gender,users.last_online,users.credits,users.activity_points,users.home_room,users.block_newfriends,users.hide_online,users.hide_inroom,users.vip,users.account_created,users.vip_points,users.machine_id,users.volume,users.chat_preference,users.focus_preference,users.pets_muted,users.bots_muted,users.advertising_report_blocked,users.last_change,users.gotw_points,users.ignore_invites,users.time_muted,users.allow_gifts,users.friend_bar_state,users.disable_forced_effects,users.allow_mimic,users.rank_vip " +
                          "FROM users " +
                          "JOIN user_auth_tickets " +
                          "ON users.id = user_auth_tickets.user_id " +
                          "WHERE user_auth_tickets.auth_ticket = @sso AND ip_last = @lastIp " +
                          "LIMIT 1"
    );

    dbConnection.AppendParameter("sso", authTicket);
    dbConnection.AppendParameter("lastIp", getIp());

    Load(dbConnection.ExecuteReader());
}
```

Here is the Load method..

```
public void Load(MySqlDataReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Id = reader.GetInt32("id");
        Username = reader.GetString("username");
        Credits = reader.GetInt32("credits");
        Diamonds = reader.GetInt32("vip_points");
        Duckets = reader.GetInt32("activity_points");
        Gender = reader.GetString("gender").ToUpper() == "M" ? PlayerGender.Male : PlayerGender.Female;
        Motto = reader.GetString("motto");
        Outfit = new PlayerOutfit(HabboUtilities.GetFilteredFigure(reader.GetString("look").ToLower()));
        Rank = reader.GetInt32("rank");
        HomeRoom = reader.GetInt32("home_room");
        VipId = reader.GetInt32("rank_vip");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us structure of your data base i.e. column name. I guess there should be some different name for rank column.

Comment: If the column was different I would have noticed. The column for rank is called 'rank'.

Comment: Have you tried to execute this same query with same input locally before putting it into code. Your database structure and data would be helpful.

Comment: I've ran the same query yes, I have perfect output from the query as expected. @Prasadtelkikar my structure and data don't matter here, the issue is in the code, I've already told you the structure and data really, the column 'rank' is an int with a length of 11 with the value 8.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that my MySqlDataReader wasn't retreiving the data correctly from the database.